# Error fetching password in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `USER` and a column called `UserPassword varchar(100)`.

If I query the `user` table:

```
SELECT UserPassword 
FROM "USER"
```

it returns

```
0x9F19488027B745FA80E2C27F3DCDCD5D7845AA74B12AB26882F617D0517F73B8
```

If I query the value:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', '13149066');
```

it returns

```
0x9F19488027B745FA80E2C27F3DCDCD5D7845AA74B12AB26882F617D0517F73B8
```

At this point both results match and have the same datatype.

But when I'm trying to match them I don't get any results.

```
SELECT "Name" 
FROM "USER" 
WHERE UserPassword = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', '13149066');
```

Returns:

```
0 records found
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT "Name" 
FROM "USER" 
WHERE UserPassword = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST('13149066' AS varchar(100)));
```

This returns:

```
0 records found.
```

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: Doesn't Hashbytes return bytes and you're comparing it against a string? How does UserPassword get populated?

Comment: https://dusted.codes/sha-256-is-not-a-secure-password-hashing-algorithm

Comment: Hashbytes does indeed return varbinary

Answer (score 6):

These records are not the same. HASHBYTES returns a VARBINARY type.

You can see this here:

```
select binary_checksum(CAST('0x9F19488027B745FA80E2C27F3DCDCD5D7845AA74B12AB26882F617D0517F73B8' AS VARCHAR(8000)))

SELECT binary_checksum(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', '13149066'))
```

The varchar vs varbinary will not match. You need to cast them to the same type or change the datatype on your user table to store the pw hash as varbinary(8000).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dfundako.
your answer helps a lot

I just change the datatype of the password field to int and i did this

```
SELECT "Name" from "USER" 
where UserPassword = binary_checksum(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', '13149066'))
```

I get the desire result.

Comment: I would recommend you double check that. I doubt your userpassword is a signed bigint.